# Modify binary tree

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures, tree

Given a binary tree. Modify it in such a way that after modification you can have a preorder traversal of it using only right pointers. During modification you can use right as well as left pointers.

somebody suggest the approach?
if instead of preorder we had inorder then we could modify the tree to BST
How to do the question if instead of preorder we had postorder traversal?

Comment: In the interest of honesty, is this a homework question set to help you learn?

Comment: this is an interview question

Comment: Your question is poor. It leaves anyone who has the good will to answer it to define everything. It does not fit the criteria in http://stackoverflow.com/tour How is that for reasons?

Comment: i just need an idea to solve the problem, how that comes to define everything?
i have not asked for pseudocode or proper code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This comes down to linearizing the tree. Pre-order traversal visits the nodes in the order parent, left subtree, right subtree. If we want to do this using only right pointers, the left subtrees have to be empty. The idea for this is to re-arrange the subtrees. Let the right pointer point to the original left subtree. Then let this subtree's last node's right pointer point to the original right subtree.

Here is the idea:

```
Node* Linearize(Node* root) // returns the subtree's last node
{
    //if it's a leaf node
    if(root->left == NULL && root->right == NULL)
        return root;

    //if there is no left subtree
    if(root->left == NULL)
        return Linearize(root->right);

    //if there is no right subtree
    if(root->right == NULL)
    {
        root->right = root->left;
        root->left = NULL;
        return Linearize(root->right);
    }

    //both subtrees exist
    Node* left = root->left;
    Node* right = root->right;
    Node* lastOfLeft = Linearize(left);
    root->right = left;
    root->left = NULL;
    lastOfLeft->right = right;
    return Linearize(right);
}
```